# Compare Column names from 2 diff table in diff db in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get column names from 2 diff tables in diff db and compare them to see if there is any extra column in any table. They should match exactly. One possible solution could be getting all the column names from both table and dump in a temp table side by side and compare? Pls help.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#myTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #myTable

CREATE table #myTable (
    table1 varchar(100) null,
    table2 varchar(100) null
 )

 INSERT INTO #myTable (table1)
     SELECT name
     FROM sys.columns
     WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('table1')

select * from #mytable
DROP TABLE #mytable
```

Comment: Is this a one time deal? i.e. can you use a schema compare tool (Redgate/Devart/Idera/etc.)?

Comment: Instead of temp tables you could just pull the columns into sub-selects and do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` on them, and look for any records that are missing one of the sides

Answer (score 0):

I modified your query to this

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#myTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #myTable
CREATE table #myTable
(
 rowNum int IDENTITY(1,1),
 table1 varchar(100) null
 )
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#myTable2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #myTable2
CREATE table #myTable2
(
 rowNum int IDENTITY(1,1),
 table2 varchar(100) null
 )
 GO

USE database1 --your 1st database name here
GO

INSERT INTO #myTable (table1)
      (
        SELECT
            name
        FROM sys.columns
       WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('Table_1'))
GO

USE database2 -- your 2nd database name here
GO

INSERT INTO #myTable2 (table2)
        (
        SELECT
            name
        FROM sys.columns
        WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('Table_2'))
GO


SELECT table1,table2
FROM #myTable m
 FULL OUTER JOIN #myTable2 m2 ON m.rowNum = m2.rowNum
ORDER BY table1,table2
DROP TABLE #mytable
DROP TABLE #mytable2
```

Comment: You might want to add an ORDER BY just to be explicit about inserting the columns in the same order in both cases.